# A Python Wrapper or Handler for A Minecraft Server

Tags: python, controller, subprocess, wrapper, minecraft

I am using Windows and am looking for a handler or wrapper using Python for a Minecraft server so that I can automatically enter commands without user input. I have searched through many questions on the website and only found half answers (in my case at least). I believe I will need to use the subprocess module but cannot decide which to use at the moment I am experimenting with the Popen functions. I have found an answer which I modified for my case:

```
server = Popen("java -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
while True:
    print(server.stdout.readline())
    server.stdout.flush()
    command = input("> ")
    if command:
        server.stdin.write(bytes(command + "\r\n", "ascii"))
        server.stdin.flush()
```

This does work in some way but only prints a line for every time you enter a command, which cannot work and all my efforts to change this end up with the program unable to execute anything else and instead just read. This is not a duplicate question because none of the answers in similar questions could help me enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already know, your `server.stdout.readline()` and `input("> ")` are blocking your code execution.
You need to make your code non-blocking, by not waiting to actually return what you want, but by checking, if there is anything to read and ignore it, if there isn't and continue to do other things.

On Linux systems you might be able to use [select module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html), but on Windows it only works on sockets.

I was able to make it work on Windows by using threads and queues. (note: it's Python 2 code)

```
import subprocess, sys
from Queue import Queue, Empty
from threading import Thread

def process_line(line):

    if line == "stop\n": # lines have trailing new line characters
        print "SERVER SHUTDOWN PREVENTED"
        return None
    elif line == "quit\n":
        return "stop\n"
    elif line == "l\n":
        return "list\n"

    return line

s = subprocess.Popen("java -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

def read_lines(stream, queue):
    while True:
        queue.put(stream.readline())

# terminal reading thread
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=read_lines, args=(sys.stdin, q))
t.daemon = True
t.start()

# server reading thread
qs = Queue()
ts = Thread(target=read_lines, args=(s.stdout, qs))
ts.daemon = True
ts.start()

while s.poll() == None: # loop while the server process is running

    # get a user entered line and send it to the server
    try:
        line = q.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        pass
    else:
        line = process_line(line) # do something with the user entered line
        if line != None:
            s.stdin.write(line)
            s.stdin.flush()

    # just pass-through data from the server to the terminal output
    try:
        line = qs.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        pass
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this as I lost hope finding anything similar that actually worked. I'm really sorry that I noticed this late because I could see there wasn't going to be an instant reply. Thanks you :)